# Accessing FacesContext in Portal Application

Tags: websphere-portal, facescontext

We need to get certain information from `PortletRequest` in our Portal application. We do that using a utility method inside our Portlet Application. In this Utility method we access `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequest()` to get the PortletRequest. We access this Utility method in our DAO layer. We do not have access to request parameter here.
It works sometimes, but at times it gives me `NullPointerException`. I found a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883893/accessing-facescontext-in-util-jar-from-multiple-portlets) which explains about this. They have mentioned, if it is part of the same request, then you should get the Context. For me, it is part of the same request, but I'm not getting the context. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a null FaceContext from FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() then no FacesContext has been constructed for this Thread/Request.

Are the failing requests coming through a non-faces entry point? Such as an Event or Resource portlet request? If so there will be no FacesContext created.

Rather than relying on static methods and thread local storage to access data in you DAO you should consider extracting what you need from the PortletRequest, and passing it down your stack. It is bad practice to mix presentation layer artefacts such as the FaceContext or a PortletRequest with your DAO layer.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is deployed in separate WAR/JAR files, it is likely that different classloaders are used. I had a similar problem, when I tried to access the FacesContext inside an hibernate HAR archive on JBOSS5. I came up with a successfull solution using reflection API. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007789/can-i-access-facescontext-inside-hibernate-event-listener).

If you bundle your whole application into one EAR, you might be able to force the use of one classloader for the whole ear, but AFAIK that is application server specific.

Regards