# How to access FacesContext in Hibernate Envers without Seam?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, hibernate-envers

We're implementing Envers in our project for database auditing, and have run into a snag. We don't know how to determine what user is making the change. All the examples I can find use Seam and their Component.getInstance technique.

- Glassfish 3.1.2.2
- Mojarra  2.1.13
- Hibernate 4.1.6.Final

Here's our custom Revision Entity

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    private String login;

    getters/setters...
}
```

And out custom Revision Listener

```
public class CustomRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {
    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        CustomRevisionEntity rev = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;

        //how do we get the FacesContext/remote user?

        rev.setLogin("unknown");
    }
}
```

We've tried injection and scoping to no avail, we also attempted this [ClassLoader solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007789/can-i-access-facescontext-inside-hibernate-event-listener) I found for something that seemed to be a similar circumstance, but getCurrentInstance() was still null;

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that `FacesContext.getCurrentInstace()` works only on requests processed by the Faces Servlet filter. Maybe you're calling this method in a non-JSF request.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hibernate Envers. But this sounds like some kind of background job which thus doesn't run in the very same thread as a HTTP servlet request. Is this true? Or does it actually run in the same thread as a HTTP servlet request? How exactly does Hibernate Envers trigger its events? In a servlet filter or request listener? (which thus runs before creation and after destroy of `FacesContext` and thus explains why it's `null`).

Comment: It runs in the same thread, and FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() should work well.

Comment: @adamw: as said, it won't work if this code is invoked before creation and after destroy of `FacesContext`, as confirmed by OP's own answer. The `FacesServlet` is the one responsible for creation and destroy of `FacesContext`. So if any code runs before or after it is invoked, then you will get `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adamw was correct, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() does work in a custom RevisionListener.

We had a javax.servlet.Filter implementation attempting to handle the transaction in the doFilter() method which was for whatever reason causing FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() to return null in the RevisionListener. We removed that from the web.xml yesterday for a different reason and when I tried getCurrentInstance() without it this morning, everything works fine.

Thanks for the replies everyone, maybe this will help someone else someday.