# JPA auditing with user id

Tags: hibernate, jsf, ejb, ear, hibernate-envers

I want to implement auditing in my web project. Basically, my app is composed by a Web Project (WAR) that call methods in a EJB Project (JAR), everything is wrapped inside an EAR which is deployed in a container (Jboss and probably Websphere in the near future).

So, I got the user session on the web side and the entities and DAOs on the ejb side. I would like to implement an auditing procedure on some user transactions, so the data state should be persisted on the database together with the id of the user who performed the change.

I can easily pass the user id on every call to the EJB side and perform the auditing from within the business methods, but that would clutter my business and client methods.

I have looked into [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers), which is a very interesting Auditing framework, but it doesn't audit the user id out-of-the-box. So I looked further and found out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609394/how-to-access-facescontext-in-hibernate-envers-without-seam), which explains how to use a **RevisionListener** to get the user id from the session and store it in the database. However, it doesn't seem to work in a EAR architecture for the following reason: this RevisionListener uses FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() in order to obtain the user id from the session, so this implies that the RevisionListener should be on the Web side of the app, not on the EJB side...

Well, I hope I had made myself clear enough :)

Cheers!

Comment: Which type of EJBs are you using: Session beans and/or JPA javax.persistence.Entity beans?

Comment: My EJBs are all @Stateless, and my entities are javax.persistence.@Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have stateless **session beans** which contain your business logic, the name of the **authenticated user** is already passed into your EJBs

You could use `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` to get the name of the calling user.

Requirements

- The web app uses a `login-config` (defined in `web.xml`)
- The JBoss web application uses a `security-domain` (`jboss.xml`); other application servers should have a similar pattern to implement login/authentication

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure I can go this way. My application may be deployed in a different container, specially Websphere, so I cannot rely on Jboss specific configuration. Sorry I've mentioned Jboss on my question, I'm going to remove that reference.

Comment: Currently I'm storing logged user information only in the JSF/Servlet session.

Comment: The security-domain is the JBoss specific implementation, it's the backend for the login-config. The pattern of having a login-configuration is available in other containers as well. If you have the user information in the web layer only, somehow it has to be passed to the EJB - explicitly by an argument or implicitly by using a principal. The WebSphere counterpart of a JBoss *login module* is the *custom user registry* - just a different name, same pattern.

Comment: Great Beryllium! I'll look into this "principal" pattern. cheers!